# PHP time and date function is not working

Tags: php, date, time

PHP timestamp is showing wrong,showing 4:30 minutes less than actual time.

```
    date_default_timezone_get('India');
    $time=time();
    $actual_time=date('H:i:s A', $time);
    echo 'The time is'.$actual_time;
```

or

```
    date_default_timezone_set('India');
    $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone')))
    {
        echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
    }
```

Comment: try this: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time= time();
$atime = date('h:i:s A',$time);
echo $atime;
?>
```

Use  `date_default_timezone_set()` instead of `date_default_timezone_get()`
This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Write This. This will solve your problem

```
date_default_timezone_get('Asia/Kolkata');
    $time=time();
    $actual_time=date('H:i:s A', $time);
    echo 'The time is'.$actual_time;
```

Or

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone')))
{
    echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
```